# Предикатив или ошибка в употреблении деепричастного оборота?

Tags: грамматика

Здравствуйте! В песне одного моего знакомого автора есть строки:

...Рождается мотив,
Несложный и приятный.
ЕГО НАПЕВ ЕДВА,
Придёт к стихам охота...

Я имел неосторожность указать автору на необходимость заменить выделенную строчку, сказав, что это ошибка - не согласован деепричастный оборот. На что он ответил, что подобная конструкция вполне себе имеет право на существование и называется предикатив. Тогда я принялся лазить по Интернету, но НИГДЕ не обнаружил подобных конструкций в качестве примеров предикатива. Кто из нас прав? Спасибо.

Answer (score 3):

Возможно,Ваш товарищ перепутал  и хотел сказать, что ПРИДЁТ ОХОТА - фразеологизм, являющийся предикативом, т.е. сказуемым: придёт охота писать стихи = захочется писать стихи. Такое выражение "имеет право на существование", но к нему нельзя присоединить деепричастный оборот "ЕГО НАПЕВ ЕДВА", как Вы совершенно верно заметили, потому что основное действие и добавочное должен исполнять один деятель(подлежащее), а у нас мотив напевает кто-то, а придёт "охота к стихам", по значению равная безличной конструкции. К безличной конструкции нельзя присоединить деепричастный оборот, только к инфинитивной

Comment: Уточнил. Действительно, предикатив - это "придёт к стихам охота". В таком случае я не совсем верно сформулировал проблему. Автор считает, что здесь нет ошибки в согласовании деепричастного оборота, потому что за ним идёт предикатив. На мой взгляд, ошибка всё-таки есть)

Comment: >деепричастный оборот "ЕГО НАПЕВ ЕДВА",
Напоминает Камеди-клаб... и его веселых резидентов, вместе всех взятых...

Comment: А  как  задавший  вопрос  определяет  деепричастие,  интересно ?

Comment: Извиняюсь.  Я  принял  слово  "напев"  за  существительное. Мне  контекста  не  хватило.

Comment: Спасибо  Инне.

Comment: Спасибо автору вопроса)

Answer (score 1):

Деепричастия совершенного вида образуются с помощью присоединения суффикса -в- к основам инфинитива на гласный:
прочитать — прочитав,толкнуть — толкнув. Соответственно, напеть - навев. У деепричастий несовершенного вида благозвучней: напевая.